# Create Excel Columns Dynamically

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I am creating a excel using namespace "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

I have list of users that I am getting from Database. That users list will change frequently.

```
Dim officers As List(Of String) = List.[Select](Function(p) p.OfficerAssigned).Distinct().ToList()
```

How can I create column for each user ? After B, its C and after C, its D. How can I dynamically increase the column alphabet ?

```
Dim aRange As Range = ws.Range("B2", "B2")
    aRange.Merge(1)
    aRange.Value2 = officers(i).ToString()
```

Comment: @gunr2171 I am sorry. I forgot to add vb.net in tags. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a referenced object for the current worksheet of "worksheet" and you want to start at column "A" and it is the first row...

```
For I as int32 = 1 to officers.count
 worksheet.cells(1,i) = officers(I-1)
Next
```